# How to restrict the access to the OS drive and to a set of actions for specific local users in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, administration

We are managing a pool of Windows 11 machines that essentially run as autonomously bookable servers used to analyze microscopy images. The computers are accessible physically or through Windows RDP (once connected to our institutional VPN) and they have identical hardware, two local Windows users ("Admin" and "User"), and 3 physical drives (C, D and E). As commonly, the C drive is where the OS and all our applications are installed.

For security and ease of maintenance, we would at least like to prevent the local Windows user "User" from:

1. Writing/deleting files stored on the C drive (including the local User folder)
2. Installing/uninstalling software (on any drive)
3. Mounting and accessing a USB storage
4. Modifying Windows registry
5. Modifying the icons on the desktop
6. Turning off or restarting the computer
7. Applying any Windows, driver (and ideally software) update

Of course, this shouldn't disrupt the regular operation of the applications.

What is the simplest and safest solution to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Writing/deleting files stored on the C drive (including the local User folder)

You should examine the permissions of the folders on C and ensure
that "User" does not have access, or that access is restricted to
administrators.

Some folders are required, the most-used one is `C:\Users\User`.
You may relocate such folders to another disk.

> Installing/uninstalling software (on any drive)

This requires administrator permission, so is disabled for "User".

However, you cannot prevent "User" from installing portable software
which does not require installation.

> Mounting and accessing a USB storage

This can done by creating a GPO.

See for example
[How to Disable or Enable USB Drives in Windows using Group Policy](https://woshub.com/how-to-disable-usb-drives-using-group-policy/).

> Modifying Windows registry

This also requires administrator permission.

> Modifying the icons on the desktop

The folder `C:\Users\User\Desktop` is owned by the user, so this will
need to be set to "Admin" and for "User" to have only Read and
Execute permissions.

> Turning off or restarting the computer

This is also feasible using a GPO. See
[Allow or Prevent Non-Admin Users from Reboot/Shutdown Windows](https://woshub.com/allow-prevent-non-admin-users-reboot-shutdown-windows/).

> Applying any Windows, driver (and ideally software) update

This will normally also require administrator permission.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

About the first point, would you have a list of Windows C folders that I should not set to Read and Execute only permissions for non admin? I'm afraid that restricting the whole C drive might impede some applications to run normally when run from the User session (when they store local settings in ProgramData or Temp folders).

About software installation, I tested it and on this computer at least by default the User session (non admin), I can install software from MSI packages or EXE installers. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: That depends on the installation - an installation that is strictly one-user and does not affect the registry or system folders does not require administrator permissions. Otherwise, you should examine the UAC settings.

Comment: I would also like to prevent regular users pinning/unpinning items to the taskbar. For this I looked into the Administrative templates from GPO, especially "Lock Taskbar" and "Lock the taskbar settings" but none seem to be effective. Do you know how to do it? Actually, I do not know how to apply a specific GPO rule to only a set of users.

Comment: This might require a separate question.